# Error when importing pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

I installed pyspark in macOS.
Then I get an error when importing `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` as a package.

```
Import "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

What is the reason?

Comment: AFAIK, `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` is not available for import, but you can import `pyspark` and refer `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` class

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame class is being exported in the sql module, you can just use the following import:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
```